# How to insert a boolean value to a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, boolean, sql-insert

I come from **MySQL** to **PostgreSQL** then, I created **`test` table** with **BOOLEAN `state` column** in **PostgreSQL** as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  state BOOLEAN -- Here
);
```

But, I couldn't insert **`TRUE`** with **`1`** and **`FALSE`** with **`0`** to **`test` table** as shown below even though the SQL queries below work in **MySQL**:

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0);
```

Then, I got the error below:

```
ERROR:  column "state" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
```

So, how to insert a boolean value to a table?

Comment: That's because the integer `1` is something different than the **boolean** value `true`. But MySQL accepts everything as a boolean expression even strings e.g. `where 'bla'` is the same as `where false` and `where '1to3'` is the same as `where true` in MySQL

Answer (score 7):

You can insert **`TRUE`** with **`'1'`** and **`FALSE`** with **`'0'`** in **PostgreSQL** as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('0');
```

Then, **`t`** which is **`TRUE`** and **`f`** which is **`FALSE`** are inserted to **`test` table** as shown below:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM test;
 state
-------
 t
 f
(2 rows)
```

In addtion, these SQL queries below also work to insert **`TRUE`** and **`FALSE`** to  **`test` table** as shown below:

### `TRUE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES (tRuE);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('TrUe');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('T');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('t');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('YeS');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Y');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('y');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('oN');
```

### `FALSE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES (fAlSe);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('FaLsE');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('F');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('f');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('No');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('N');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('n');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('oFf');
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to insert boolean values in PostgreSQL is to use the literal boolean values `true` or `false` or any expression that evaluates to a boolean.

For example:

```
create table test (
  state boolean
);

insert into test (state) values (true);
insert into test (state) values (false);
insert into test (state) values (3 * 5 > 10);    

select * from test;
```

Returns:

```
state
-----
t
f
t
```

See running example in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iuScb-nn).